# Writing a program to print a "Hello, world!" program

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I just started reading Accelerated C++ and I'm trying to work through the exercises when I came across this one:

`0-4. Write a program that, when run, writes the Hello, world! program as its output.`

And so I came up with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << helloWorld << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void helloWorld(void)
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

I keep getting the error `'helloWorld' : undeclared identifier`. What I figured I was supposed to do is make a function for helloWorld then call that function for the output, but apparently that's not what I needed. I also tried putting `helloWorld()` in main, but that didn't help either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `helloWorld()` needs to be _declared_ before it can be used.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the assignment asks. They want you to write a program that prints "Hello, World!" or a program that prints the *code* for a "Hello, World!" style program? The two are subtly different.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Going from the quoted text it should clearly be the later.

Comment: Did you meanwhile rethink your accept decision? You should have a look on 
[Code-Apprentice's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842842/2932052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not actually *calling* your `helloWorld` function anywhere.  How about:

```
int main()
{
    helloWorld(); // Call function

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: You'll also need to declare your function prototype at the top if you want to use it before it's defined.

```
void helloWorld(void);
```

Here's a [working sample](http://ideone.com/MWuCYR).

Comment: And you need to declare helloWorld() first.

Comment: Oh I see.. I just figured if that since the problem wanted me to make a program write "Hello, world!" as its output that I needed to put it between cout. Well, at least I know how to call functions now. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @iKyriaki - Yup, I guess now you're supposed to write a program that outputs the *above program*... or something.

Answer (score 11):

The way I read the textbook exercise is that it wants you to write a program which prints out *another* C++ program to the screen. For now, you need to do this with a lot of `cout` statements and literal strings surrounded by `""`s.  For example, you can start with

```
cout << "#include <iostream>" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Surprising to read iKyriaki's comment [on the "accepted" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842835/2932052) ;)

Answer (score 3):

To call a function, you need to:

- Provide a declaration prior to its use
- Follow its name with a pair of parantheses, even if it doesn't have any arguments.
- Provide a return value in order to use it in an expression.

For example:

```
std::string helloWorld();

int main()
{
   cout << helloWorld() << endl;
   ...
}

std::string helloWorld()
{
    return "Hello, world!";
}
```

Comment: Uhm... considering that `helloWorld` is a void function, this won't work even with the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
hellwoWorld();
```

instead of `cout << helloWorld << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, `helloWorld` is not a declared variable.

You want `hellowWorld` to be a string whose contents are the hello world program.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the compiler you are using, you might need to put helloWorld function before your main like this.

```
void helloWorld(void)
{
    .....
}
int main()
{
    .....
}
```

I use visual studios and I am forced to do this ....

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need the helloworld function defined at the bottom. Something like this should do it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //cout will output to the screen whatever is to the right of the insertion operator, 
    //thats the << to it's right. 
    //After "hello world" the insertion operator appears again to insert a new line (endl)
    cout << "hello world" << endl;

    //cin.get()  waits for the user to press a key before 
    //allowing the program to end
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```